# Matlab Errorbar Not Working

Tags: matlab, errorbar

I'm running Matlab2015a on Windows 8.1; recently I formatted my computer, and after reinstalling the software the "errorbar" function is not working anymore.

When using a code like

```
      figure
      x=rand(10,1);
      y=rand(10,1);
      error=rand(10,1);
      errorbar(x,y,error,'.b','markersize',12);
```

Matlab opens a new figure and plots the points, but no error bars appear; no error or warning message is given in the Command Window.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software, but nothing changed. The function used to work perfectly before formatting the computer.

Any idea of the source of this problem?

Comment: Maybe your error values are to small to be visible? Please give a complete example (including `x`, `y` and `error`)

Comment: Thanks for replying; I updated the code in the question.

Comment: `err` is undefined. Changing it to `error` I get [this output](http://abload.de/image.php?img=untitled0us3a.png) which has error bars in it.

Comment: Sorry, I just copied the code wrong from matlab. Changing err to error I get the upper figure in [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9uehHGsOMXyNWh5WTBVcEZ1TUU/view?usp=sharing) pdf (that's what matlab shows to me). I noticed however that exporting an eps or a pdf the bars are shown (see the second figure)

Comment: What is the renderer that your figure is using (`get(gcf, 'Renderer')`). Also what version of MATLAB?

Comment: The renderer is used is `opengl`.However forcing Matlab to use `painters`  as renderer (`set(gcf,'renderer','painters')`) the bars are shown.
I am running Matlab2015a.